# apt freezes mid-install/uninstall every time, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, dpkg, btrfs

I'm out of ideas how to fix this, it has persisted across reboots, apt updates, apt upgrades, even a `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

The nice thing is I have two machines both behaving this way, both are raspberry pi's (Raspberry Pi 4 Model B), and both freeze at the "Progress:" bar of the apt command:

```
Taking backup of bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Ignoring old or unknown version 5.4.0-1059-raspi (latest is 5.4.0-1060-raspi)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1043-raspi

Progress: [ 60%] [################################################################################################################...........................................................................]
```

Some factors I've tried checking, the systems run btrfs on `/`, but the filesystem continues to show clean scrubs. They are also running pihole, so lots of DNS activity but I'm not sure how that would affect apt...

Hope someone here has an idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in `apt` or anything else that would indicate that package management is broken or outdated?  Or does it not even get to that point?  When did the problem start?  What led up to the problem's onset or since you last ran `apt` successfully?

Comment: No, no lead-up it has always been like this on these machines. I create my own base images to push to raspberry pi's and this is an issue with all of them. Apt will complete if you give it enough (very long) time, but the terminal usually exits and it finishes in the background. No errors in /var/log/apt/term.log, no errors when it completes you just get truncated output. Only way to see if it's done is open a separate terminal and watch via `top` or similar.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is not a problem with the images that Ubuntu publishes for raspi. (I personally have several running Ubuntu without issue)  Many many people use these images and every raspi is identical to every other raspi of the same model. Keeping that in mind, it seems the only common denominator would be your custom base image or some other situation that exists on your pis that isn't on anyone else's. Can you elaborate on all of the modifications you made? In order to solve an issue like this, we have to know the cause.

Comment: Nmath, maybe I'm not being clear. These are custom images made by me (i.e. NOT stock).

Comment: You may have misunderstood my comment. I had asked to elaborate on the details about all of your modifications because that's where the problem is likely to originate. I only mentioned the stock images in contrast. Stock images don't have these problems so the only variables are whatever modifications have been made. It's extremely easy to rule out the hardware or the stock images. There's only so many raspi models. Because each model is identical to every other board of the same model, we know exactly how the "stock" raspi image will behave on these devices.